# Re: checking if triplets of integers occur in a list - why does my code give the wrong answer for one specific test case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

Here is the task I am given:

Write a function find_if_triplet(), which receives a single parameter, my_list, a list of integers, with values in ascending order.

The function returns a single boolean, has_triplet, which is set to True if an element of the list my_list appears at least three times. It returns False otherwise.

For instance,
if my_list = [1,1,1], the function should return has_triplet = True, if my_list = [1,2,3,3,3], the function should return has_triplet = True, if my_list = [1,2,2,2,2,3], the function should return has_triplet = True, if my_list = [1,2,2,3,4,4,5], the function should return has_triplet = False.

I tried to use the Python count() function to check if an integer in the list occurs at least thrice. While it works for most test cases i.e. when my_list = [1,1,1] or [1,2,3,3,3] or [1,2,2,3,4,4,5], when my_list =[1,2,2,2,2,3], it doesn't. Instead of the boolean returning a True (has triplets) it incorrectly returns False. Why could this be?

```
def find_if_triplet(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
    instances = my_list.count(i)
    if instances >= 3:
        has_triplet = True
    
    else:
        has_triplet = False

return has_triplet
```

Comment: rather than set the variable `has_triplet` every iteration of the list (which potentially resets it to False even though you know the final answer to be True, if the test is True then just `return True` right there. then if your loop runs to completion you can just `return False`.

Comment: Hint: Your test cases have the triplet as the last items in the list. Do you really need to continue looking for a triplet once you've found one?

Answer (score 1):

The indentation in the original question is flawed. What's probably needed is this:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_if_triplet(my_list: list[int]) -> bool:
    if len(my_list) > 2:
        for x in set(my_list):
            if my_list.count(x) > 2:
                return True
    return False

# if you prefer Counter to do all the work for you then:

def find_if_triplet2(my_list: list[int]) -> bool:
    if len(my_list) > 2:
        _, n = Counter(my_list).most_common()[0]
        return n > 2
    return False
    

lst = [1,2,2,2,2,3]

print(find_if_triplet(lst))
print(find_if_triplet2(lst))
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
```

**Note:**

The fact that the input list is sorted (ascending) is irrelevant in this implementation

Answer (score 0):

since you are looping through the list and then using `list.count` on each element, then for each element this function count the frequency of that number in entire array for each value.

also in your code, if for any value lets say in `[1,2,2,2,2,4]`  for each value has_triplet value changes as (for each index) `[False, True, True, True, True, False]`
since you are taking the final value of has_triplet as return, you are getting final value ie wheter if last number is has_triplet True or not only.

so to solve this issue, you can use counter fujnction or make your counter function as

```
def find_if_triplet(array):
    has_triplet = False
    freq = {}
    for num in array:
        if num not in freq:
            freq[num] = 0
        freq[num] += 1
        if freq[num] >= 3:
            has_triplet = True
            break # once found triplet stop search further and end the looping
    return has_triplet
```